# How can i publish my android application without certificate?

Tags: android, certificate, apk

I has build an .apk with a server but I can't install it on a android device keytool:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
```

How can I publish my application without certificate ?

Comment: How do you even export it without keystore?

Comment: @jonathan.cruz in a previous android sdk version I saw that option in some submenu.

Comment: You really should not try do to that, certificates are used for a reason.

Comment: @jonathan.cruz you can right click on the project and go to Android Tools - > Export unsigned package.

Comment: @rekire ok, i never saw that :)

Comment: @Raghav i found it :) nice to know, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact location, but it's there somewhere. I'd look it up and tell you, but I'm on the mobile. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. No app store will let you upload an unsigned apk, and even if they do, no Android device running an unmodified version of Android will let you install the apk without a signature.

This is why even eclipse uses a debug certificate to sign your app during the development process. Additionally, certain APIs and libraries like Google Maps will not be usable without a signed binary.

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to do. [Here is a link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) with just about everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload it to any appstore, you can't.
If you want to send it to people that knows you and trust you, it can be done...

- On the **end user** phone system menu, choose `Settings/Applications/Unknown sources`, then install from SD card, file attached to an email or any other source
- You can **self sign your application** as explained here: http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/apk/